# How to calculate fft using rest api in django, by using the csv file passed by the user using POST request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a code that take in post request from the server ie, a file and store it into my local drive.

What I am looking to solve is to read the file uploaded and store it into the db.sqlite3 database, and pass a post request using rest api to perform fast fourier transform calculations on the csv data that the user upload.
Using rest api only.

I have created a api to get the file from the user,

I am not able to find out a relavent solution regarding the issue, thanks for the help in advance.

the csv file uploaded is this:

```
time, amplitude, 
0,0.73904, 
0.02441,1.2372, 
0.04883,1.0019, 
0.07324,0.50924, 
0.09766,-0.603, 
0.12207,-1.6674, 
0.14648,-1.5332, 
0.1709,-0.85486, 
0.19531,0.3971, 
0.21973,1.3604, 
0.24414,1.8384, 
0.26855,1.7446, 
0.29297,0.73904, 
0.31738,-0.69308, 
0.3418,-1.6969, 
0.36621,-1.6215, 
0.39063,-0.97252, 
0.41504,-0.07721, 
0.43945,0.78132, 
     .
     .
     .
```

There are 2549 lines in total

Here is my model.py file

```
from django.db import models

class Files(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(blank = False, null = False)
    remark = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

serializers file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . models import Files

class FilesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta():
        model = Files
        fields = ('file', 'remark', 'timestamp')
```

this is the view file

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

from .serializers import FilesSerializer

class FileView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        file_serializer = FilesSerializer(data=request.data)
        if file_serializer.is_valid():
            file_serializer.save()
            return Response(file_serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I would like to add on with this code snippet as this is not in rest API, views.py file

```
def index(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        file = request.FILES["document"]
        csv = pd.read_csv(file)
        sf = 40960
        samplingFrequency = sf;
        samplingInterval = 1 / samplingFrequency;
        time = csv['time']
        amplitude = csv['amplitude']
        fourierTransform = np.fft.fft(amplitude)/len(amplitude) 
        fourierTransform = fourierTransform[range(int(len(amplitude)/2))] 
        tpCount     = len(amplitude)
        values      = np.arange(int(tpCount/2))
        timePeriod  = tpCount/samplingFrequency
        frequencies = values/timePeriod
        plt.title('Fourier transform depicting the frequency components')
        plt.plot(frequencies, abs(fourierTransform))
        plt.xlabel('Frequency')
        plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
        plt.show()
        fig = plt.fft()
        buf = io.BytesIO()
        fig.savefig(buf, format = 'png')
        buf.seek(0)
        string = base64.b64encode(buf.read())
        uri = urllib.parse.quote(string)
         return render (request, 'visual/index.html', {"something": True, "frequency": frequencies, "amplitude" : amplitude }, {'data':uri})
    else:
        return render (request,'visual/index.html')
```

Here in this code, the time value is from the csv and the sampling frequency is taken in from the user using api.

Hope this helps.
Thank you for the effort.

Comment: Just wanted to check if you have code for the part where you get fft excluding the django part?

Comment: @VJMagar yes i do will share you the link here **https://pythontic.com/visualization/signals/fouriertransform_fft** please look into this.

Comment: any luck @VJMagar

Comment: Kinda. I will work over it. Give till weekend I will share the answer.

Comment: Hi @Manoj, can you update your question with the code snippet of how you planning to use the time and amplitude to get fft. (Unfortunately, I kind of getting bit confused when I am trying to translate the values into numpy array)

Comment: @VJMagar i have updated the code that i used without using the rest API hope this helps, thank you for working over the issue.

Comment: Ah. I was confused with how we were consuming time in fft calculation. Thanks. Another quick one, you need to return the location of graph generated or share the graph so that it can be directly rendered (as in base64)?

Comment: I understand the situation I had been in that too, anyways hope it helps, we actually wanted to display it a separate page I did this by keeping this in mind however it would pop up as a new python plotter so was confused there too.

Comment: I have updated the code again please have a look, thank you..